# What pathfinder 2e features, if any, can be used to replicate / emulate the features of a 5e transmutation wizard?

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-2e, conversion

I run a 5e campaign for a group of friends. I've recently suggested transitioning over to PF2e. One of the players is playing a transmutation wizard, and he's fond of his Minor Alchemy ability:

> Starting at 2nd level when you select this school, you can temporarily alter the physical properties of one nonmagical object, changing it from one substance into another. You perform a special alchemical procedure on one object composed entirely of wood, stone (but not a gemstone), iron, copper, or silver, transforming it into a different one of those materials. For each 10 minutes you spend performing the procedure, you can transform up to 1 cubic foot of material. After 1 hour, or until you lose your concentration (as if you were concentrating on a spell), the material reverts to its original substance.

Are there any options (focus spells, feats, etc.) that would grant this player a similar capability?

Answer (score 3):

The [Precious Metals focus spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=440) (from the [Wealth](https://2e.aonprd.com/Domains.aspx?ID=36) Domain) is fairly similar. It only works on metal, so you miss the wood and stone aspects, but it does expand its list to include cold iron, and eventually mithril and adamantine, giving it slightly better combat effectiveness than the 5e equivalent (especially considering Precious Metals is 1 action).

As this is a domain spell, it's rather difficult for a Wizard to acquire. You'd have to do so through something like grabbing the [Cleric Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=694) at level 2, then [Basic Dogma](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=696) for [Domain Initiate](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=265) at level 4, then [Advanced Dogma](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=697) for [Advanced Domain](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=285) at level 16. However, you could probably homebrew a feat for Wizard similar to Advanced Domain that'd give access to the focus spell, and I don't think it'd be overpowered or anything. You could instead use the [Oracle](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=42) or [Champion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=4) archetypes with a similar set of feats.